# how much resources my PHP app cosumes?

Tags: php, performance

I'm wondering if there are tools that can measure how much resources (CPU/RAM) my PHP app uses?

I want to test my app by simulating multiple requests to different urls and see how much resources consumes? Also simulate multiple connections i.e. simulate that a defined number of users are using my app.

is it possible? what do you recommend?

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Linux, top is the way to go ( at least for me ).

I keep one tab running top so I can watch the ram/cpu/etc as I load various pages/apps.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

Comment: thanks, that should work as starting point, but I'm looking for more advanced tools if they exist

Comment: top is impressively advanced.  When running, hit "h" for information about what you can do.  I usually hit "1" after running top as I like to see more detail about which cpus are being used.